# Breakdown and understand sentences containing contradictory(or somewhat opposite sounding) phrases

Tags: phrases, contractions, complex-sentences

While I was reading today about the items that are sold in a 7-eleven, I bumped into this a sentence(5th sentence from top) like below on this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twizzlers):

> Because Twizzlers ingredients do not include extracts of the licorice
> plant, they are referred to as licorice-type candy.

It's just me or the sentence is consisting of 2 contradictory sounding phrases and raises confusion and question instead of clarifying the idea ?

The question being "Why would the possibility of the Twizzlers containing or being made-from the extracts of Licorice plant, would prevent them from being referred to as `licorice-type` candies ?"

Also how can someone break it down and completely grasp the true meaning conveyed in these type of sentences that contain opposite sounding phrases ?

Comment: Read the statement again and think about it.

Comment: Already read umpteen times. If I just had to do that and magically the answer would have to be just popped up in my mind then I wouldn't have taken the effort to ask it here, common knowledge. If you know the answer, just write it here..

Comment: *"Why would the possibility of the Twizzlers containing or being made-from the extracts of Licorice plant, would prevent them from being referred to as licorice-type candies?"*  - It wouldn't. But that's not at all what that sentence says, it says that Twizzlers do *not* contain licorice extracts so they can't be sold as "licorice". There's no contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the Wikipedia article carefully you will find that the Y & S Candies originally made liquorice confections. That is sweets which contain a significant percentage of liquorice.

All Twizzlers originally contained liquorice but the modern range has many other flavours most, if not all, of which have no liquorice in them but the style of the candy is exactly the same as  the original ones which did.

The company cannot call them 'liquorice candy' because that would be a lie and they could be sued or prosecuted for doing that so they call them "liquorice-type candy" which gives a good idea of the style of the product but does not state that they contain liquorice.

A similar piece of naming is "woodgrain finish". This is a paint, plastic, or printing finish which is applied to a product made from material which contains no wood in order to make the product look at least a bit like wood. Plastic furniture, kitchen cabinets and worktops, electrical goods, and car interiors have all had this treatment applied to them in the past although it is no longer as fashionable as it was.

What the sentence is telling you is that Twizzlers, although they look and feel like liquorice candy, they do not, in fact, contain any part of the liquorice plant so they can't be called "liquorice candy". The sentence also says that the company's answer to this problem was to invent the term "liquorice-type candy" which says that it is similar to liquorice candy but implies that there is no liquorice used in its formulation. There is no contradiction in this because the term "liquorice-type candy" specifically says that it contains no liquorice.

In the UK at least users of the terms "soya milk", "almond milk" and so on have recently been subjected to complaints that, as the products contain no milk, this should be made clear on the packaging and in advertising so they are now appearing with descriptions such as "soya drink", "almond milk alternative" and so on. This is another example of the same thing.

Comment: *Licorice-type candy* (the phrase) does ***not*** specifically mean that it contains no licorice. It simply means that it's similar to licorice, but shouldn't actually be considered to be licorice. It's quite possible that a licorice-type candy could contain *some* licorice, but just not enough for it to be considered licorice on balance. (What that percentage might be, I don't know. But that's not the point.) If I'm eating a piece of bread that contains a small amount of licorice extract to flavour it, it might be licorice-like, but not actually licorice (it would still be bread).